# My code gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This piece of code giving me type error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
I don't understand what is the problem here.

```
const ShowMainData = ({ name, rating, summary, tags, image }) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={image ? image.original : IMG_PLACEHOLDER} alt="show-cover" />
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <div>
                <Star />
                <span>{rating.average || 'N/A'}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: summary }} />
    
            <div>
              Tags:{' '}
              <div>
                {tags.map((tag, i) => (
                  <span key={i}>{tag}</span>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: Are you passing a defined `tags` prop that is an array or object with a `map` property that is a function? Can you update your question to include a more comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added`?.` before map:

```
const ShowMainData = ({ name, rating, summary, tags, image }) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={image ? image.original : IMG_PLACEHOLDER} alt="show-cover" />
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <div>
                <Star />
                <span>{rating.average || 'N/A'}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: summary }} />
    
            <div>
              Tags:{' '}
              <div>
                {tags?.map((tag, i) => (
                  <span key={i}>{tag}</span>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```

or you can check if `tags` is not undifined by doing this:

```
const ShowMainData = ({ name, rating, summary, tags, image }) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={image ? image.original : IMG_PLACEHOLDER} alt="show-cover" />
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <div>
                <Star />
                <span>{rating.average || 'N/A'}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: summary }} />
    
            <div>
              Tags:{' '}
              <div>
                {tags && tags.map((tag, i) => (
                  <span key={i}>{tag}</span>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue happens because your `tags` variable is undefined, you may not be passing it as a prop. Safer alternative is:

```
    const ShowMainData = ({ name, rating, summary, tags, image }) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={image ? image.original : IMG_PLACEHOLDER} alt="show-cover" />
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <div>
                <Star />
                <span>{rating.average || 'N/A'}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: summary }} />
    
            <div>
              Tags:{' '}
              <div>
                {tags&& tags.length> 0 ? tags.map((tag, i) => (
                  <span key={i}>{tag}</span>
                )):null}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```